# Enter password for git pull in script

Tags: windows, git, bash

I would like to create a script/tool which runs through my repositories and makes git pull. Script asks me a pass from GitLab/Bitbucket/whatever, I enter it and script synchronizes all repos hosted there. The problem I have faced: I have no idea how to enter password automatically.

For example, options like these do not work:

```
yes ${STORED_PASSWORD} | git pull
echo ${STORED_PASSWORD} | git pull
```

From googling and reading Stack Overflow, I have understood:

- Passing password as a part of url is not safe;
- Credentials helper needs to enter password once for ***each*** remote repo and it will continue to store passwords after script will finish its work.

I use Windows's git shell, and there is no `expect` tool. Are there any options or workarounds?

Comment: Git allows to automaticly work (without entering password) via ssh using ssh keys
https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/

Comment: @oybek, I would prefer to confirm my actions by password entering

Comment: Have your considered implementing your helper as described here: https://git-scm.com/docs/api-credentials#_credential_helpers ?

Comment: you could try the `cache` handler, but I'm not sure it exists at Windows

Comment: git for windows has this: https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows . It looks quire feature reach, maybe it fits your goal

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, using SSH instead of HTTPS makes perfect sense in your use case, as it is less unwieldy and won't have you accidentally reveal your password to other users of your machine.

If you insist on using HTTPS and passing your password, this approach will work:

`git pull https://myusername:${STORED_PASSWORD}@mygithost.com/my/repository`